# Listing items on eBay

Tags: windows, gratis, ecommerce, ebay

I'm looking to empty out a cupboard or two and wish to list items in bulk. I have problems with eBay's clunky and slow site, so I'd rather create something locally, then hit "Go" and have it list the items on eBay, uploading images etc. These are my requirements:

- free
- Windows 7/8 compatible
- upload images
- save products locally for relisting as and when I want if it doesn't sell
- not SaaS, for it to be on my computer - I want to own my data
- allow me to enter the postage cost (for the country I'm in, UK) rather than needing w/h/l and weight dimensions to 'calculate' it
- allow me to use a 'profile' so that I don't have to specify that it's for a 30 day listing each time
- preferably open source

I'm currently using WordPress on a virtual machine locally which comes very close to what I want, but that isn't able to upload images properly which means I have to - after listing - edit each item and upload images!

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I last used Windows on an old Laptop, I used **[TurboLister](http://pages.ebay.co.uk/turbo_lister/)** for this. Was really convenient (miss something like that on Linux now):

[image: TurboLister] [image: TurboLister]
<sup>*TurboLister* (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Let's see how it meets your requirements:

- **free:** yes.
- **Windows 7/8 compatible:** [its homepage](http://pages.ebay.co.uk/turbo_lister/) states at least Windows 7 compatibility.
- **upload images:** yes.
- **save products locally for relisting as and when I want if it doesn't sell:** yes. And even syncs them with the online listing – so if you have later changes, you won't need to use the clunky web interface.
- **not SaaS, for it to be on my computer - I want to own my data:** check :)
- **allow me to enter the postage cost:** yes.
- **allow me to use a 'profile' so that I don't have to specify that it's for a 30 day listing each time:** If you're talking about templates: AFAIR yes. Not sure about profiles.
- **preferably open source:** unfortunately no.

As this software comes from eBay itself, it usually gets fast updates if things at eBay change and of course can make use of APIs at their latest stage (plus even of those not public).

Comment: I actually downloaded this before you wrote this! The software UI is a bit 'old' but it sure does seem to tick all the boxes - open source was a requirement mainly out of trust but as it's from Ebay directly, I'll let it slide. I will use it with some listings and if I'm happy certainly mark this as the answer

Comment: Well, the UI for this is slow and clunky - not too sure if it's faster than using the site, but it allows for CSV import so I'll knock a better UI together with HTML and jQuery. WARNING: listings made with this don't seem to be accepted for the (completely) free listings of your allowance.

Comment: As I wrote, my own experiences date back a couple of years. There were definitely things to complain about – but it was still faster than doing everything online, especially due to the templating and relatively easy copy-and-paste, and I had all my data available on my own computer. So it's far from being perfect – but "a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush" :)

Comment: Maybe it's gotten worse. Adding images is painful causing the program to lock up after each one, and even moving from input to input causes it to lock up. So, I'll just knock together something that helps creating the CSV file as that should really help speed things up! Thanks

Comment: Anytime! There was also Jaolt (a Java application I currently use), but it's no longer maintained (even the project site seems to have disappeared, and the Ubuntu PPA has been deleted). For more alternatives, see the links [on this German page](http://www.alternative-zu.org/alternativen/jaolt/). Not that I could see something fully fitting your requirements.

Comment: It seems that they've discontinued TurboLister and are no longer offering it for download.