# Linux software to list items on eBay

Tags: gratis, linux, ebay

Analog to [Listing items on eBay](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/32100/185), I'm looking for an application running on Linux. Up to now I've been using Jaolt, but that's no longer available (which is why I cannot even provide a link) – setting up a new machine and lacking the source, I thus cannot even install the old version anymore. I want to prepare my "sales" locally on my computer (so no SaaS / web service unless I can host it myself). For those not familiar with Jaolt, just check [my answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/32115/185) on the linked question for a "visual description" of eBay's own *Turbo-Lister* (which was available on the Windows platform until recently).

[image: Jaolt] [image: Jaolt]
<sup>*Jaolt* item edit and bid watcher (old screenshots; click to enlarge)</sup>

In detail, here are my requirements:

**MUST have:**

- prepare items locally (not on some other website)
- editor for item description. No need for fancy stuff here: a simple HTML or Markdown editor is fine.
- loads categories from eBay and lets me connect them with my items.
- allows to attach images (and uploads them to eBay)
- allows to set (multiple) shipment costs (e.g. one for shipping with insurance, one for without, one for "local pickup")
- save my complete item locally for reuse
- must run on Linux, best with no dependency on a specific desktop environment (e.g. no KDE stuff). The machine will run on Cinnamon. "Light dependencies" are OK (and expected) – "Wine" doesn't count as such, Python would be acceptable, just to give examples.

**Strongly wished for:**

- saving default settings, such as how long the auction should last
- check "consistency" before upload (to see if it would be accepted, or if details are missing) and show me the eBay cost for listing the item
- watch online auctions (manual poll is fine, i.e. update the local list on-demand with number of visitors, watchers, bids and the current price)

**Real nice-to-have:**

- templates for the editor (or at least the possibility to create/maintain your own templates)
- macros for often used "phrases", like standard disclaimers or pointing out reduced shipping cost when multiple items are bought
- preview before uploading

**Not needed, but welcome:**

- searching eBay's resources for matching descriptions/images (possible e.g. for books by ISBN)
- support for fixed prices. I rarely use that and can do without.
- multi-account support

Open source preferred, but not mandatory. Free of cost, private use only (so no commercial license required). I only use it every now and then, so buying something hardly is an option (though I might consider something for below EUR 20 if it's really overwhelming and I can test it before ;)

---

<sup>If you know a perfect match for Windows, please head over to the linked question and answer it. The current only-answer is probably no longer valid, as eBay stopped the *Turbo-Lister* application.</sup>

Comment: Its a shame Turbomaker is going down- you could of just ran it In WINE.

Comment: @DanBrown Urgs... Nope, no wine. I knew I forgot something...

Comment: Now that's just making it difficult :)

Comment: @DanBrown if it were easy, I'd already self-answered it – or not asked it at all. I'm already looking for the better of a year, and was not able to turn something up. I'm prepared to have an unanswered question here – but I've not yet given up hope I might have overlooked something, e.g. some Python app.

Comment: There might be something. I was going to say SixBit, but you pay for it.

Comment: Hmmmm..... It seems JAOLT can be be grabbed from other places - though how legitimate the source is can be questioned. I'll poke around.

Comment: And while I'm poking around, try https://www.inkfrog.com/ It may need Wine, I don't have an EBay account to try it with. (EDIT) these seem to be JAOLT alternatives https://sourceforge.net/directory/?q=jaolt+ebay+lister

Comment: @DanBrown Inkfrog seems to be SaaS (it's definitely browser-based, and reviews have it login takes you to their site). I see no explicit mention of install requirements, and all sounds very much cloudy. The absolute no-go argument is: *…unless you pay a monthly subscription your items will have adds for the app unless you pay a monthly subscription at $11/mth min." Apart from which, only 5 listings are "free".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48370/discussion-between-dan-brown-and-izzy).